# Create a lazy stream of all anagrams of a given word

Tags: java, algorithm, java-8, anagram

I'm trying to write code to create a lazy stream of all anagrams of a given word. I was using this code originally:

```
public static Stream<WordSequence> anagram(Stream<WordSequence> data, Object[] parameters) {
    return data.unordered().flatMap(WordSequence.forEachWord(Functions::allAnagrams)).distinct();
}

private static Stream<Word> allAnagrams(Word data) {
    if (data.length() <= 1)
        return Stream.of(data);
    Stream<Word> ret = Stream.empty();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
        char ch = data.charAt(i);
        String rest = new StringBuilder(data).deleteCharAt(i).toString();
        ret = Stream.concat(ret, allAnagrams(new Word(rest)).map(word -> new Word(ch + word.toString()))).unordered();
    }
    return ret;
}
```

(I'm using my own `WordSequence` and `Word` classes.)

I realized that this was not very efficient because it's just concatenating a bunch of empty and one-element streams, and it also computes all the anagrams before returning the stream of them. I found this wonderful algorithm in Core Java somewhere:

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(word);
for (int i = b.length() - 1; i > 0; i--)
    if (b.charAt(i - 1) < b.charAt(i)) {
        int j = b.length() - 1;
        while (b.charAt(i - 1) > b.charAt(j))
            j--;
        swap(b, i - 1, j);
        reverse(b, i);
        return new Word(b.toString());
    }
return new Word(b.reverse().toString());
```

If you call it with a word, it will return the next word in a sequence of all the anagrams of the word.

I implemented it as follows:

```
public static Stream<WordSequence> anagram(Stream<WordSequence> data, Object[] parameters) {
    class AnagramIterator implements Iterator<Word> {
        private final Word start;
        private Word current;
        private boolean done;

        AnagramIterator(Word start) {
            current = this.start = start;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return !done;
        }

        @Override
        public Word next() {
            if (done)
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(current);
            for (int i = b.length() - 1; i > 0; i--)
                if (b.charAt(i - 1) < b.charAt(i)) {
                    int j = b.length() - 1;
                    while (b.charAt(i - 1) > b.charAt(j))
                        j--;
                    swap(b, i - 1, j);
                    reverse(b, i);
                    current = new Word(b.toString());
                    done = current.equals(start);
                    return current;
                }
            current = new Word(b.reverse().toString());
            done = current.equals(start);
            return current;
        }

        private void swap(StringBuilder b, int i, int j) {
            char tmp = b.charAt(i);
            b.setCharAt(i, b.charAt(j));
            b.setCharAt(j, tmp);
        }

        private void reverse(StringBuilder b, int i) {
            int j = b.length() - 1;
            while (i < j) {
                swap(b, i, j);
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        }
    }
    return data.flatMap(WordSequence.forEachWord(w -> StreamSupport.stream(
            Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(
                    new AnagramIterator(w),
                    Spliterator.DISTINCT + Spliterator.IMMUTABLE + Spliterator.NONNULL),
            false)));
}
```

However, that algorithm has a problem. If you give it a word that ends with a double letter and then another letter, where the double letter value is numerically less than the single letter, such as "ees", you get this sequence of anagrams:

```
ees
ese
ees
and that repeats infinitely
```

That sequence doesn't include "see".

How can I do this?

My code is [on GitHub](http://github.com/tbodt/trp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought about what the algorithm was doing and had a flash of insight. Given the string "ese", this is what the algorithm does:

- Find `i`, which in this case points to the s.
- Find `j`, which points to the e.
- Swap `i - 1` and `j`, which swaps the two e's.
- Reverse the string from `i` onward, which swaps the s and the e.

What we want it to do is have `j` point to the s too, which would make it swap the first e and the s. So how can we modify the algorithm to make that happen?

Well, here's what it does to find `j`:

- Start by pointing `j` at the last e.
- `i - 1`, which is an e, is not greater than `j`, which is the other e, so `j` points to the last e.

Here's my flash of insight: change the comparison from "greater than" to "greater than or equal to". I changed that, and it seems to have worked!